# Video streaming from image processor

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, video, image-sensor

The project I'm working on involves streaming video from an image sensor to an LCD, preferably as cheaply as possible. My question is: can I get an image processor/sensor SOC (a la https://www.aptina.com/products/soc/mt9v117d00stc/) and stream that data directly to an LCD, then only using the MCU to initialize those two components? Or do I need the MCU to act as a buffer between the two and feed the data from the image processor to the LCD? Unfortunately I don't have access to the datasheet for the image SOC just yet, so I understand if it's hard to say for those specific systems. But the general question still remains: do I need an intermediate MCU for video streaming between an image processor and an LCD for anything other than initializing communication?

Comment: You would need an MCU with System On Chip (hardware) encoding of video formats, such as that found on the Raspberry Pi main processor. The LCD screen would need to have it's own video format decoder and onboard drivers for the display. This would be very simply the MCU turning on the system and letting it run, with very little effort (or programming) on your behalf. Just a matter of selecting the correct devices and testing they work in harmony :)

Comment: @KyranF not even close to being correct. Why code and decode when there is no transmission or storage requirements?  It's simply a reformatting issue and timing issue.  perhaps one frames worth of memory needed to allow for manipulation.

Comment: @placeholder streaming video through an encoded format would only need a frame or two worth of buffers. Why would you say I'm not even close to being correct? Maybe I used the wrong word, but what I said is exactly what you then said.

Comment: @KyranF To paraphrase you - "first encoding on an SOC and then decoding in the TV set would be required". None of that is required.

Comment: @placeholder depending what you are trying to interface with. For example a raspberry pi can make use of it's H.264 encoding hardware to output via HDMI very good quality video to a TV or other device capable of decoding/displaying H264. Otherwise, the IC mentioned by the OP has quite a few options for output, and something cheap with just a parallel or analog video input might work straight away.

Comment: @KyranF you say " you need" as apposed to " one solution is ..."

Comment: @placeholder righto, sorry mate! I hope somebody has more direct experience with this form of video IC straight to an LCD screen because I did some serious Googling and could not find an easy "plug and play" solution at all.

Comment: @KyranF I can appreciate your trying to help the person who asked the question but giving wrong information muddies the water and makes it more difficult to get to the true answers.

Comment: Frame buffering is not needed when interfacing to LCD with parallel RGB interface, but some glue logic is necessary because the sensor outputs each pixel in two 8-bit halves.

Comment: @akohlsmith in my given scenario/combination of components, I am correct. It's not the full answer, and that is certainly why I did not post it as one.. pretty sure there are multiple ways to skin a cat, or design an embedded system/circuit/whatever so saying my opinion or suggestion is "wrong" or as placeholder said "not even close to being correct" is not very fair at all.

Comment: @KyranF Does HDMI transfer h.264 compressed video?

Comment: @venny no, sure doesn't!

Comment: @venny if you are referring to this part of my comments earlier: "For example a raspberry pi can make use of it's H.264 encoding hardware to output via HDMI very good quality video to a TV or other device capable of decoding/displaying H264" I agree it's not worded properly, the RPI does the H264 related stuff on board and the RESULT is transmitted over HDMI to an appropriate TV/monitor/whatever can use it. None of that is relevant if the original video stream was not originally in the H264 format of course. I have extremely low experience in video streaming/related systems though, forgive me.

Comment: @KyranF no, you're incorrect. That is the issue. You start your comment with "you would need" as if you are certain. The question specifically asks for the cheapest solution. It's not a matter of skinning a cat many different ways. You're not giving an answer that's even in the same ballpark as "correct" and that's the issue.

Comment: @akohlsmith okay then, sorry guys. Please, offer better solutions.